# Quit Flutter integration tests

Tags: flutter-integration-test

I have made an integration test for my flutter project based on [this documentation](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/testing/integration/introduction) which looks like this:

```
void main() {
  IntegrationTestWidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  group('end-to-end test', () {
    testWidgets('tap on the floating action button, verify counter', (tester) async {
      app.main();
      await tester.pumpAndSettle();

      // Verify the counter starts at 0.
      expect(find.byKey(Key('settingsButton')), findsOneWidget);
    });
  });
}
```

The key is on an IconButton:

```
IconButton(key: Key('settingsButton'),
                iconSize:...
```

Unfortunately the test just hangs in `06:05 +0: loading /Users/...` and only quits after 12! minutes with the following message: `12:00 +0 -1: Some tests failed.`

1. Is there any way to quit a running integration test?
2. Is there any way to see why it hangs and why it failed?

I am using Android Studio.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way to quit a running integration test?

If you're running your tests with `flutter test integration_test`, then you should be able to simultaneously press "CTRL" and "C" to cancel execution.

> Is there any way to see why it hangs and why it failed?

It's hard to tell without being able to reproduce your issue. Try running `flutter test --verbose integration_test` – it may contain some clues.